# Looking for a specific value in JSON file

Tags: python, json, iterator, key

I have a json file created by a function.

The file is looks like this :

```
    {
  "images": [
    {
      "image": "/WATSON/VISUAL-REC/../IMAGES/OBAMA.jpg", 
      "classifiers": [
        {
          "classes": [
            {
              "score": 0.921, 
              "class": "President of the United States", 
              "type_hierarchy": "/person/President of the United States"
            }, 
            {
              "score": 0.921, 
              "class": "person"
            }, 
            {
              "score": 0.73, 
              "class": "ivory color"
            }, 
            {
              "score": 0.648, 
              "class": "Indian red color"
            }
          ], 
          "classifier_id": "default", 
          "name": "default"
        }
      ]
    }
  ], 
  "custom_classes": 0, 
  "images_processed": 1
}
```

I wrote a function that is going to check is a the value "person" is present. 
If the value "person" is present, I will increment with

```
#LOADING MY JSON FILE  
output_file = open(new_json_file).read()
output_json = json.loads(output_file)
#SETTING PERSON VALUE TO 0 
person = 0 
#CONDITIONS 
if "person" in output_json["images"][0]["classifiers"][0]["classes"][0]["class"] :
    person=1
    print (' FUNCTION : jsonanalysis // step There is a person in this image')
    return person
else :
    person = 0
    print (' FUNCTION : jsonanalysis // step There is a NO person in this image')
    return person
```

I guess This is not the right way to check if the value "person" is returned in the JSON Key since it does not find the value. What Am I missing here ?

I looked into some threads like those and tried to adapt my function:

Parsing values from a JSON file using Python?

Find a value within nested json dictionary in python

But my issue is the "class" key. There is several values for the key "class" ( like "ivory color") not just "person".

Comment: @ roganjosh  : Ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the "person" class is not necessarily the first in the first element of the "classes" array. you should iterate over all of the elements there.

```
for entry in in output_json['images'][0]['classifiers'][0]['classes']:
    if ('class' in entry) and (entry['class'] == 'person'):
        person += 1
        print (' FUNCTION : jsonanalysis // step There is a person in this image')
        return person
```

if you want to check if there is 'person' in a class entry in ANY of the images/classifiers, you will need to iterate over those arrays as well:

```
for image_entry in output_json['images']:
    for classifier_entry in image_entry['classifiers']:
        for class_entry in in classifier_entry["classes"]:
            if class_entry['class'] == 'person':
                person += 1
                print (' FUNCTION : jsonanalysis // step There is a person in this image')
                return person
```

Note, that if you want to count the total number of 'person' occurrences, you should not return inside the loop, but only after it is completed.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

1 Lets assume your data is stored into the python dict, if not try to convert it.

```
   data_dict =   {
   "images": [
   {
  "image": "/WATSON/VISUAL-REC/../IMAGES/OBAMA.jpg", 
  "classifiers": [
    {
      "classes": [
        {
          "score": 0.921, 
          "class": "President of the United States", 
          "type_hierarchy": "/person/President of the United States"
        }, 
        {
          "score": 0.921, 
          "class": "person"
        }, 
        {
          "score": 0.73, 
          "class": "ivory color"
        }, 
        {
          "score": 0.648, 
          "class": "Indian red color"
        }
      ], 
      "classifier_id": "default", 
      "name": "default"
     }
   ]
  }
  ], 
  "custom_classes": 0, 
  "images_processed": 1
 }
```

2. Convert the json to string using following:
        import json

   ```
    data_str = json.dumps(data_dict)
   ```
3. Now check the word in the string (data_str):

   ```
    if 'person' in data_str:
         return True
    else:
         return False
   ```

Comment: This method will yield many bad results. for example, it will match even if there is the string 'xxxpersonxxx' or if 'person' is a key etc.

Comment: changing the format was my old workaround. But I would like to keep going through the json.

Comment: The data is already `json`, and this might only be a snippet of a much larger file so this could have a lot of false positives for the type of tests the OP might want to do.

Comment: yeah, its kinda hack, the real solution would be an very fast json c language parser and then tokenize every word and then lookup is performed would.